# AWS Route 53: Transferred domain to new account - Now getting SERVFAIL

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, nslookup

I recently transferred a domain `buymy.coffee` to a new account. When I did this, I deleted the hosted zone in the old account and recreated it in the new account. I thought I got this right, but when I do an `nslookup` I get the error:

```
** server can't find buymy.coffee: SERVFAIL
```

I waited 10 days just to be sure this wasn't a caching issue.

Here's some additional information:

[Route 53 hosted zone entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi9JW.png)

[Domain Registration entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqAl9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a lame delegation scenario, see https://dnsviz.net/d/buymy.coffee/YlRerw/dnssec/

In short the nameservers at registry do not match the nameservers in the delegated zone. Until that is fixed, no reliable DNS service can be guaranteed.

```
$ dig @$(dig NS coffee +short | tail -1) buymy.coffee NS +noall +auth
buymy.coffee.       1h IN NS ns-718.awsdns-25.net.
buymy.coffee.       1h IN NS ns-128.awsdns-16.com.
buymy.coffee.       1h IN NS ns-1310.awsdns-35.org.
buymy.coffee.       1h IN NS ns-1601.awsdns-08.co.uk.
```

vs

```
$ dig @ns-718.awsdns-25.net.  buymy.coffee NS

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1 <<>> @ns-718.awsdns-25.net. buymy.coffee NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Sending:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16686
;; flags: rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: da92eec7b8a2a23b
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;buymy.coffee.      IN NS

;; QUERY SIZE: 53

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 16686
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

So the nameservers used (set at registry for the delegation) are not the correct one or they are not configured correctly. Inquire with your DNS provider.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Trying to reach out to AWS for support on this. Do you know of a way to see a history of nameservers for this domain? I deleted the hosted zone entry in a different AWS account. (I'll upvote as soon as I have enough rep)

Comment: https://completedns.com/dns-history/ shows domain created on March 15 with same nameservers. Your registrar should be able to give you full previous history of the domain as nameservers change have to be down through the registrar. Registrar and DNS provider are two completely separate jobs, that can be done by a single entity if so chosen.

Comment: The easiest and fastest way to fix this is going to be to update the name server at the registrar (domain registration entry). They should match the name servers listed at the TOP of the Route53 console screen (expand "Hosted zone details").

You will also want to fix your NS entry (in Route53) to match the values at "Name servers" the TOP of the Route53 console screen as well.